# How to change TextView with the change of the ImageView in a Carousel in Android

Tags: java, android, text, carousel

I am working on a project in which I have created a Carousel using this [library](https://github.com/sayyam/carouselview).

I also want to show the Image Description in a TextView which should change as the image changes.
I am unable to change the TextView as the image changes. What should I do to make this happen?

My Java Code:

```
public class Carousel extends AppCompatActivity {
CarouselView carouselView;

int[] sampleImages = {R.drawable.a,R.drawable.b,R.drawable.c,R.drawable.d};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about_devs);

    carouselView = findViewById(R.id.carouselView);
    carouselView.setPageCount(sampleImages.length);
    carouselView.setImageListener(imageListener);
}
ImageListener imageListener = (position, imageView) -> imageView.setImageResource(sampleImages[position]);
```

My XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/retro_red"
tools:context=".AboutDevs">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/pragya"
    android:text="@string/about_devs"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.074" />

<com.synnapps.carouselview.CarouselView
    android:id="@+id/carouselView"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.235" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I know this might be a silly thing to ask but I am unable to figure it out. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your xml I can see that you are using Carousel View Library as you've mentioned but Carousel View Lib doesn't supports Image Listener, so your best bet would be to change you library either, or use Fragments in your activity, learn more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure If I understand your qyestion correctly, but

```
    ImageListener imageListener = new ImageListener() {
        @Override
        public void setImageForPosition(int position, ImageView imageView) {
            imageView.setImageResource(sampleImages[position]);
        }
    };
```

Can't you just add setting your textview value in this method?